# Watch OS : NSUrlSession Credential caching

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, watchos-2, nsurlsessionconfiguration, nsurlcredential

I want to implement "logout  and new login" feature from iPhone and Apple Watch.

- I am able to clear the credentials from iPhone (Using NSURLConnection because its old code) after logout, but not able to from apple watch (Using NSURLSession).
- I am using NSURLSession in Apple Watch as it is new and recommended by Apple.
- I tried with ephemeralSessionConfiguration to connect with server from apple watch (Watch OS 2.0, Swift 2.0, iOS 9.0 >> ). I called: 'invalidateAndCancel' 
  and `resetWithCompletionHandler`  APIs to clear the credentials and no change in the behaviour.
- Only one time it is firing the authentication challenge. After that it is always using the credentials which I provided first time. So I am not able to use the new logged in user credentials.
- I tried to get the Credential store and cache to clear the credentials. But the shared credential store and cache is empty.

**Question**

Is there anything wrong with my approach ? or Is it a bug of Watch OS 2.0 ?

Comment: any update on the issue?